# Symfony2, source path url in assetic for dev environment

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I have this code block in twig:

```
{% javascripts
    '@CommonBundle/Resources/public/js/*'
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

In dev env it is compiled in something like:

```
<script src="/js/96bb269_part_16_main_1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/96bb269_part_16_mwheelIntent_2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/96bb269_part_16_plugins_3.js"></script>
```

But I want real source path in urls for dev env like:

```
<script src="/CommonBundle/Resources/public/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="/CommonBundle/Resources/public/js/test/mwheelIntent.js"></script>
<script src="/CommonBundle/Resources/public/js/foobar/plugins.js"></script>
```

Output parameter is not a solution in this case (it works for hole block but not the each `<script>` line), I just want to stop compiling asset urls for dev env (or maybe modify this method). What I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is what you want -
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment

Comment: You should post this as an answer, silly. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must to copy the real resources to a `web/bundles` dir. For this use some build-in appropriate commands in symfony console

Comment: How it can help me? I already have symlinks in it. And how web/bundles dir is used by Symfony btw?

Comment: Read the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html), please. Maybe it will be usefull